# Why might there be this error in my OBS websocket?

Tags: python, websocket, obs

Just doing the basic obs WebSocket examples I've found. In the OBS client it looks like it briefly connects but then they all end up with this error:

```
Exception has occurred: KeyError
'status'
  File "obswebsocket_tests.py", line 3, in <module>
    client.connect()
```

Here's my code:

```
import obswebsocket, obswebsocket.requests
client = obswebsocket.obsws("localhost", 4444)
client.connect()
v = client.call(obswebsocket.requests.GetVersion()).getObsWebsocketVersion()

print(v)

client.disconnect()
```

And here's my OBS client view:
[image: OBS Client]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest release of [the obs-websocket-py library (0.5.3)](https://github.com/Elektordi/obs-websocket-py) was on December 20th 2020.
Version 28 of OBS, released on August 3rd 2022, comes with the new WebSocket plugin version 5.

From [their blog post](https://obsproject.com/blog/obs-studio-and-obs-websocket-join-forces):

> Many existing tools will require the previous version of obs-websocket, 4.9.1-compat, in order to continue working until such time as those tools are updated. This version can be installed alongside v5 and will not conflict, and can safely be removed at a later date once any tools you may be using are updated to the new version. That version can be found alongside the download links for 5.0.1 on the release page.

You will need to separately install version 4 of the WebSocket plugin, from their [release page](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-websocket/releases).